# Using an XBOX360 wireless controller in WoW used to work but not anymore  (Windows 7 x64) using Xpadder software

Tags: world-of-warcraft, controllers, xpadder

I played WoW 2 months ago and I was able to use my XBOX360 wireless controller without any problem, that is great to reduce risk for RSI!

Now I cant use it anymore, why?

It works in the operating system Windows 7 x64. For example the left analog stick is the mouse and that works flawlessly in the OS?

Comment: Did you modify something during those 2 months? Did you install some drivers?

Comment: Service Pack 1 and that made ZBoard engine stop working but I found new drivers for that. But I think it strange when it works in OS?

Comment: And I asked Blizzard they said //start quote// Thank you for your email. Unfortunately World of Warcraft doesn't support any other input systems other than Mouse and Keyboard. We don't give support for Xbox 360 or any other kind of controllers. This doesn't necessarily mean that they won't work, but we have not tested them and we don't have them to make the required tests.//end quote//   But it emulates the mouse so it should be the mouse and keyboard per definition sort of but I must be wrong with this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

This was a question on a recent episode of [the Instance](http://theinstance.net).  I don't recall the exact details, but you apparently need a third-party add-on to get the controller working in WoW.  It's not in my podcatcher anymore, but I'm pretty sure it was episode 219.

Though, if the OS uses it as a mouse, it seems like WoW ought to be able to use that.

Comment: I use the Xpadder software and it worked flawlessly in Wow 2 months ago but not now.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Xpadder?

Comment: It doesn't install in runs in memory (as everything but you know what I mean). First I used a version that was free Xpadder(seven), but when this started I used a version I bought, because I found it great but that didn't work either.